# How to convert row into column with random with mysql

Tags: mysql, random, rows, ifnull

How to convert row into column with random with mysql?
Distinct (image_url)

```
 select p.email , 
        image_url AS image_url_1,
        image_url AS image_url_2 ,
        image_url  AS image_url_3,
        image_url  AS image_url_4
    FROM
        poll p
    GROUP BY
        email
    ORDER by RAND()
```

Also, in this query

```
select email,
    (select IFNULL((image_url from poll p1 order by rand() limit 1), NULL) as image_1,
    (select IFNULL((image_url from poll p2 order by rand() limit 1), NULL) as image_2,
    (select IFNULL((image_url from poll p3 order by rand() limit 1), NULL) as image_3,
    (select IFNULL((image_url from poll p4 order by rand() limit 1), NULL) as image_4
from poll
group by email
```

How to display `null` if there is less than 4 image_url and how to make it distinct?

Comment: Do you want to show one email address and four randomly chosen images from the table poll?

Answer (score 0):

```
select email,
(select image_url from poll p1 order by rand() limit 1) as image_1,
(select image_url from poll p2 order by rand() limit 1) as image_2,
(select image_url from poll p3 order by rand() limit 1) as image_3,
(select image_url from poll p4 order by rand() limit 1) as image_4
from poll
```

Comment: Expensive; could end up with the same image multiple times; and shouldn't each subquery filter on `p.email`?

Comment: Maybe it's expensive, but I don't assume that such a query is posed to a table of more than a few thousand rows. And yes, the email filter should/could be added. But as long as we don't know what the OP is aiming at...

Comment: select email,
(select IFNULL((image_url from poll p1 order by rand() limit 1), NULL) as image_1,
(select image_url from poll p2 order by rand() limit 1) as image_2,
(select image_url from poll p3 order by rand() limit 1) as image_3,
(select image_url from poll p4 order by rand() limit 1) as image_4
from poll
group by email

How could i display NULL if there is less than 4 image_url?